# Config folder for a service

Tags: centos, rpm, services, fhs

### Context

When running the Deluge daemon (deluged) as a service, you can specify an option to where the config folder will be created.

The deluge-user I've created, is a system account, and therefore doesn't have a home dir.

Deluge was installed using RPM so I guess it was installed under `/opt/deluge`.

### Question

Taking into account that Deluge is running as a service, and keep in consideration the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html), where are the most appropriate folders to place :

- The config folder of the deluged daemon ?
- The folder containing the current download (could be gigabytes of data)

I was thinking of `/var/opt/deluge`

*It's not my case, but it's not impossible that deluge runs as a service and launched by an user.*

Comment: "Deluge was installed using RPM so I guess it was installed under /opt/deluge."  Why are you guessing?  Just use `rpm` to check.

Comment: @larsks I don't have access to my server right now. But it doesn't really matter